# Passing jQuery variables to Controller via AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send the variables from the GetTelephoneFunction to the AJAX query so it can reach the controller, but what I have tried does not work. Please help and thank you.

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Status/GetUrlSource",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "url": $("#urlInput").val(), "user": $("#user").val(), "pass":$("#pass").val(),"freq": $("#freqInput").val() }),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result, status, xhr) {
        //Code
        }
    function GetUrlTelePhone(html, status, result) {
        var geturlUser = url.split('?username=')[1].split('&password')[0];
        var geturlPass = url.split("&password=")[1];
        var getUrlMain = url.split("?")[0];
        var geturlParameters = url.split("aspx")[1];
        }
```

Controller

```
    public string GetUrlSource(string url, string freq, string user, string pass)
    {
        //user = user.Substring(0, 10) != "?" ? "?" + user : user;
        //pass = pass.Substring(0,20) != "&" ? "&" + pass : pass;
        url = url.Substring(0, 4) != "http" ? "http://" + url : url;
        string htmlCode = "";
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "Not Found";
            }
        }
        //SqlConnect(url);
        Hangfire(url,freq,user,pass);

        return htmlCode;

    }
```

Comment: What happens when you debug? Does it hit your controller at all? Do you get a 404 error when the ajax runs?

Comment: What is the actual request that is being sent from this ajax call? Use the browser developer tools > network tab to watch network call details as you test.

Comment: Match this from your controller `string url, string freq, string user, string pass` to the data you're sending from the ajax call `"url": $("#urlInput").val(), "user": $("#user").val(), "pass":$("#pass").val(),"freq": $("#freqInput").val()`  They probably should be in the same order.

Comment: I think I've got it figured out. I included the username and password into the url to download string. Thanks.